# How to fix lost session in java JSP after redirect

Tags: java, jsp, session, cookies

I am currently writing a webapp where i need to login a user. When the user is logged in he needs to be redirected to an external page to get a token. The issue is that when he gets the token and is redirected back to the web application, even though he is still logged in, the session is gone and he is redirected back to login page. How to fix this? Should I use a cookie?  Session doesn't use a cookie by default?. If so, what should should I store inside the cookie? Please advice.

Comment: could you add the code of the login?

Comment: Store the session id in a cookie, then use that cookie to authenticate the user using session filter (your own session filter implementation) in java.

Comment: @Dagriel : I am just creating a session on the doPost method of the servletUser user = new User();//just a user pojo
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("User", user);
        response.sendRedirect("HomeControllerServlet");

Comment: @user1354678 : So this filter will constantly check every request if there is a cookie or a session?

Comment: yes, if you've marked the session filter's url pattern as `/*` in web.xml, all the requests will be passed only through session filter so that you can do your appropriate authentications in the filter. Check this link, it provided very good filter example.. http://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial